# Разрабока angular+yi2 на локальной машине без кросс-доменных запросов

Tags: yii2, angularjs, openserver

Здравствуйте, господа, нужна помощь.

Приложение на angular крутится на localhost:4200, рест на openserver и понятное дело идут кросс-доменные запросы.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно избежать такого поведения на локальной машине, как настроить окружение.

Настроить yii2 для кросс запросов не проблема - но не очень удобно, так как появляется лишний код, а в будующем на хостинге всеравно два приложения будут лежать в одном домене на разных поддоменах.

Заранее благодарен :)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос вот в этой статье https://toster.ru/q/375430
В итоге отсылаю запросы и кросс-доменных запросов нет.